# Proof by contradiction: If n is an integer greater than 2, then for all integers m, n does not divide m and n + m $\neq$ nm.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have been studying proof by contradictions and one of the practice problems is to prove the above proposition using proof by contradiction. The intial line I have is:

We will use proof by contradiction. We assume the proposition is false, which means n is an integer greater than 2, and there exist an integer m such that n divides m and n + m = nm.

Any suggestions on what the next step should be to reach a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

$n+m=mn$ implies that $1/n+1/m=1$. This means that when $n>2$,
$$
\frac{1}{m}=1-\frac{1}{n}>1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2},m<2.
$$
We also have $1/m<1/n+1/m=1,m>1$. So $m$ is NOT an integer, a contradiction.

Your "n does not divide m" part is confusing since everything divides 1. Note that you also have some confusion between "and" and "or". The sentence "which means n is an integer greater than 2, and there exist an integer m such that n divides m and n + m = nm" should be "which means n is an integer greater than 2, and there exist an integer m such that n divides m **OR** n + m = nm".